# Mongodb error: data.includes is not a function

Tags: mongodb, find, include, var

I am running a js script for identifying and writing field values with certain date formats (YYYY-mm-dd in this case) in a txt file. All was going well with single fields and even with one subfield, such as 'Status.dateTime', to which I wrote: `var data = ({'Status.dateTime':{$exists:true})` and worked just fine.

The problem started in the following case, in which I have a field, an array '0' and a subfield of this array. How can I declare the variables and proceed in this case?

```
db.ato.find({'Area.0.Date':{$exists:true})
   .projection({})
   .sort({_id:-1})
   //.limit(1000)
   .forEach(function(doc) {
       const fs = require('fs')
       var data = ({'Area.0.Date':{$exists:true})
       if(data != null && !data.includes("/") && data != "" && data.indexOf("-") == 4) {
            //print(doc._id + " " + data)
            fs.appendFile('C:/Users/victo/Desktop/output_query_YYYY-mm-dd.txt', doc._id + " " + data + "\n", (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            })
       }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the forEach MongoDb uses [JavaScript](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach/). So the doc inside the function is your mongodb document.

In order to get the date from the first element of the Area array inside your doc you would grab it using the JavaScript.

```
var data = doc.Area[0].Date
```

To make things more intuitive you can use

```
print(doc)
```

inside the forEach and see the JavaScript Object

Comment: Yes, that worked! Inside MongoDB structure I can use 'Area.0.Date', but in JS part (after 'forEach'), the sctructure is 'Area[0].Date'